# JavaScript method isn't working on view in Rails 6+

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to declare a method in a `JS` file and use it in the `.html.erb` like this below method

```
const getSetHtml = () => {
    console.log("Hello World");
}
```

and in the view `.html.erb` like this below code

```
onclick="getSetHtml()"
```

but it's showing

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getSetHtml is not defined

I imported files like below

```
// /app/javascript/application.js
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails";
import "controllers";
import "trix";
import "@rails/actiontext";
import "trix";
import "@rails/actiontext";
import "./bootstrap.bundle.min";
import "./editor"; // this file
```

Note: Others JS library is working fine but the custom method isn't working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to set the function with const? If it fits with your specific use case, cool! Otherwise I would personally just go ahead and define it regularly, either way here is the syntax for what you're trying to do.

```
const getSetHtml = function() {console.log("Hello World")};
```

Your current function returns the function itself rather than returning the return value of the function(the console.log("Hello World")).

I can't be entirely sure but I believe in your application.js you can just import the file like this I would try the other thing first: `import "editor";`

I hope this helps even a little, good luck. Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your function by adding it to the `global` object

```js
global.getSetHtml = () => {
  console.log("Hello World");
}
```